# Design Patterns with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns

I'm doing a web application for my Software Enginearing' exam. I decided to use Rails framework and I'm trying to learn it.

During the course we have studied Design Patterns from GoF, but I don't find anything interesting for Rails.

Can anyone adress me to some sources that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read this one [http://www.amazon.com/Design-Patterns-Ruby-Russ-Olsen/dp/0321490452](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321490452) and I found it very interesting. Both in terms of design patterns and in the way it goes under the hood of things people usually know about ruby.

Comment: Is this book useful for applying Design Patterns in rails? Or it's specific for Ruby?

Comment: It's more about the patterns themselves really. It just uses ruby to demonstrate them. Though I remember it mentions rails a lot and how the patterns are used there. In fact you will find many patterns used when you start reading rails source codes. Other than that rails itself does not enforce you to use design patterns. It's more up to you how you design your code. And then you don't care much if it is rails or plain ruby. But when it comes to design patterns I definitely recommend rails source codes. Convention over Configuration is almost everywhere in rails for just one example.